# Difference between echo and @echo in unix shells

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, echo

What's the difference between "echo" and "@echo" in the unix world?

I can't even google special characters.

For example,
as used [here](http://blog.jgc.org/2015/04/the-one-line-you-should-add-to-every.html)

Comment: You use echo to display things. Don't know whether there exists @echo in unix, I think that's in DOS.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

That's a [Makefile-specific thing](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Echoing.html); it has nothing to do with shell scripts.

Recipes that begin with `@` do not echo the command. That is to say, with a Makefile

```
foo:
    echo foo
```

You get

```
$ make foo        # <-- this is meant to be the command you enter in the shell
echo foo
foo
```

Whereas with a Makefile

```
foo:
    @echo foo
```

it is

```
$ make foo
foo
```

Comment: There's [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/), although it's been hit-and-miss for me. Apart from that: you should be able to accept the answer in a few minutes. There's a delay to make it more difficult for bots to generate each other lots of reputation (at least I think that's the reason).

Comment: which is why you really dont need "make".  the shell is sufficient, _and_ you ONLY have one tools syntax to deal with. e.g.  "newest foo /dev/null || echo foo".  I'll post "newest" below.

Comment: @Mako google queries in "quotes" should search for that exact string,, also see [Google Advanced Search](https://www.google.com/advanced_search)

Comment: I found this answer with "@echo" linux via DuckDuckGo. :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
applemcg.$ fbdy newest trace_any
function newest
{ 
    trace_call $# $*;
    [[ -f "$1" ]] || { 
        trace_call NO $1;
        return 1
    };
    t=$1;
    shift;
    while [[ -n "$1" ]]; do
        [[ "$t" -ot "$1" ]] && { 
            trace_call NEWER $1 than $t;
            return 1
        };
        shift;
    done;
    trace_call NEWEST $t;
    return 0
}
function trace_any
{ 
    printf $* 1>&2
}
applemcg.$
```

so, the "make paradigm" is

```
newest outputfile inputa inputb... || {

      command input...   > outputfile
}
```

and you cat toss your makefiles on the scrap heap of history.

Comment: How does this answer the question?